# Obtener imagen con React Native

Tags: rest, react-native, djangorestframework

construi una pequenia API con django un solo modelo perfil, estoy serializandolo con rest'framework, pero no consigo mas que traer un json con los datos de la persona y la imagen con la ruta donde se encuentra en mi proyecto.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "jorge",
    "imagen": "media/perfil/jorge.jpg"
}
```

ahora estoy con react-native trabajando ese json y pues mi imagino que la imagen deberia estar en alguna url por que con la ruta que recibo en el json no logro mostrarla en un Image de react-native.

```
<Image style={styles.cover} source={{ uri: data.item.imagen }}/>
```

lo unico que consigo como ya dije es que en mi app aparezca solo la ruta de la imagen como en el json, y no muestra la imagen quizas este invocandola mal o cometiendo errores en proyecto de django, alguien quizas podria darme una mano en esto.

Answer (score 0):

consegui crear un metodo en mi modelo serializers el cual consiste en unas tres lineas de codigo

```
def get_imagen(self, persona):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    imagen = persona.imagen.url     
    return request.build_absolute_uri(imagen)
```

con el metodo request lo eh logrado, ya que con absolute_uri me genera la ruta o path de la imgen en url.

construi una pequenia API con django un solo modelo perfil, estoy serializandolo con rest'framework, pero no consigo mas que traer un json con los datos de la persona y la imagen con la ruta donde se encuentra en mi proyecto.

{
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "jorge",
    "imagen": "media/perfil/jorge.jpg"
}
ahora estoy con react-native trabajando ese json y pues mi imagino que la imagen deberia estar en alguna url por que con la ruta que recibo en el json no logro mostrarla en un Image de react-native.

http://path/imagen.jpg' }}/>

espero que alguien e sirva de algo este resultado.